# How to build: 3D Canvas objects and manipulation - tylko.com

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Just wondering if anyone can guide me into how this site was built: https://tylko.com/shelf/bookshelves/

I've seen fabric.js in use, but not sure how to go from there. Is there any platforms or services that would assist in creating this or it's a heavy custom-build project?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was built using a technology called **WebGL**

Based on your question, I understand that you are new to the field of 3D graphics, so I would highly recommend a higher level called 'Three.js' https://threejs.org

I recommend this because using WebGL from scratch is a very daunting experience, while Three.js is simply to use by comparison.

Introduction : 
https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-fundamentals.html

If you prefer videos, I would highly recommend this guy,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jP4xpga6yY

Here is a tutorial of something similar to what you're looking for :
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/09/17/how-to-build-a-color-customizer-app-for-a-3d-model-with-three-js/

If you're looking for a prebuilt one : 
https://www.capterra.co.uk/software/156373/3d-source-product-configurator

Comment: Thank you so much - this is perfect!! Helps me in the right direction. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem what so ever, have a great day